# Should we have a new tag for qustions about learning about Hinduism?

Tags: discussion, tags

There are many questions asked by users who are enthusiastic to learn about Hinduism as well as follow it. Some of them are as follows:

- [How shall a foreigner develop their practice of Sanātana Dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/27147/5212)
- [What should I read, Where should I start, and in What sequence - when reading Hindu religious books?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/26175/5212)
- [How to read Hindu Scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/15693/5212)
- [Resources to learn about Hinduism for an ex muslim who has been agnostic for about 10 years](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/22476/5212)
- [Looking to learn about Hinduism?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/17635/5212)

I also think there will be new questions in the future. So, one of the issues is tagging these questions. So far, there is no single way of tagging these questions. Some are tagged with practice, some are with resource, etc., 
This would not be helpful if one wants to look at all the questions for beginners (I mean who are totally new to the religion) to follow. So, I feel that there should be some new canonical tag about questions about learning concepts of Hinduism like the first one and second one on the list (not for advanced topics like kriya yoga, Upanishads, Sadhana in Tantra etc.,).

As we know, new tag should not be very complicated and should be easy to search. So, what is the best tag to tag these types of questions?  I invite discussion from the community about the naming the new tag. Give your opinions as an answer.

Before proposing please read: [**the death of meta tags**](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/08/07/the-death-of-meta-tags/) by Jeff Atwood. The tags proposed should denote the topic of the question and not the user who posted the question. So, beginner, starter are not good (we are not experts to judge them). They should also be stand alone tag on the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[learning-about-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/learning-about-hinduism) can be made for the questions seeking knowledge about Hinduism.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest either [study-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/study-hinduism) or [schooling-hinduism](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/schooling-hinduism)

Comment: or [tag:welcome-to-hinduism-now-learn] will also be very useful. I feel it should be there.

Comment: No, "welcome" is not right word w.r.t. question, or is it ? @Rohit.

Comment: No, welcome is not a right word. The tag looks like a slogan. The question is about learning hinduism not welcoming to Hinduism. Welcoming etc., is for newbies but question should not indicate if user is new or old.