# Why is it shown as "modified" instead of answered?

Tags: bug, answers

This is about [answer](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1304/5212) posted by TheLittleNaruto posted 2 hours ago to the question [Should we have a new tag for qustions about learning about Hinduism?](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1299/5212) . He answered the question and didn't edit further. But it is shown as modified 2 hours ago on home page of Meta. 
 [image: image showing modified instead of answering]

But the answer was not modified and there were no revisions to the post (Checked the timeline also).

Why is this shown as "modified" instead of "answered" ?

Comment: It's clearly a bug. Report to main site of meta.SE

Comment: Grace period edit?

Comment: Grace period edit still shows as answered @BhargavRao

Comment: Are you sure bout that?

Comment: @BhargavRao Yes, during the grace period, it is shown as answered only. It shows modified after that.